# .NET Core 3.1 Get UserId from Identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity, userid

I search a lot for how to Get UserId From Identity and do not found any answer. Can you help me please with an answer for .NET Core 3.1?
I tried a lot of ways to find and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UserManager class which has method GetUserId. You can pass HttpContext.User to it and receive user id. Also check out [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuserid?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

```
var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
```

Comment: I have already tried this method and I get an error

InvalidOperationException Unable to resolve service for type `Microsfot.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'1[...] while attempting to activate '[...]'`

Comment: @PaoloConstantin can you show your controller code?

Comment: `public class KindergartenController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public KindergartenController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
public IActionResult AddComment(Comment comment)
        {
            if (HttpContext != null)
            {
                var a = _userManager.GetUserId(principal: HttpContext.User);
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Add the http context to DI:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```